# How do I switch to new tab or window in playwright-java?

Tags: java, webautomation, playwright

How can we switch to a new window that has opened while running test, and how can I get back to the parent window in playwright-java?

Answer (score 2):

There is no Switch action like Selenium. You can use the `waitForPage` or `waitForPopup` functions. You just need to know what is the action triggering that new page. e.g.

```
Page popup = context.waitForPage(() -> page.click("a"));
```

The `context` class also has a `pages()` function, which returns all the open pages.

Comment: i'm getting this `any
Property 'waitForPage' does not exist on type 'BrowserContext'` after i tried the solution above

Answer (score 2):

It works fine for me:

```
String newUrl = page.context().pages().get(index_to_switch).url();
page.navigate(newUrl);
```

but you can also try this way:

```
page.context().pages().get(index_to_switch).bringToFront()
```

Answer (score 0):

expanding on @hardkoded's answer, I got an error and am now using this:

```
context.waitForEvent('page')
```

works for my purposes so far

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is continue your test in a new page. The official docs: https://playwright.dev/docs/pages#handling-new-pages

Here is an example where we first work in the initial "page" and then, after clicking a button we want to continue our tests in a new tab we define as "newPage":

```
        // Here we are working in the initial page
        await page.locator("#locator").type("This happens in the initial page..");

        /*  When "Ok" is clicked the test waits for a new page event and assigns to new page object to a variable called newPage
            After this point we want the test to continue in the new tab,
            so we'll have to use the newly defined newPage variable when working on that tab
        */
        const [newPage] = await Promise.all([
            context.waitForEvent('page'),
            page.locator("span >> text=Ok").click()
            
        ])
        await newPage.waitForLoadState();

        console.log("A new tab opened and the url of the tab is: " + newPage.url());

        // Here we work with the newPage object and we can perform actions like with page
        await newPage.locator("#Description").type("This happens in a new tab!");
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code snippet works between tabs.

```
page.context().pages().stream().filter(x -> x.title().equals("expectedTitle")).findFirst().get().bringToFront();
```