# how do I open a link in a new tab using playwright?

Tags: web-scraping, playwright, playwright-python

I need to collect all the links from the page, open each one (alternately) in a new tab, collect data from the page and close the tab.

in selenium, I would do something similar to this:

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")
main_window = browser.current_window_handle
for elem in elems:
    ActionChains(browser).key_down(Keys.COMMAND).click(elem.get_attribute("href")).key_up(Keys.COMMAND).perform()
    browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[1])
    ... collect data ...
    browser.close()
    browser.switch_to.window(main_window)
```

How to implement this functionality in playwright?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I switch to new tab or window in playwright-java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66638076/how-do-i-switch-to-new-tab-or-window-in-playwright-java)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `modifiers` to the `click` function:

```
page.click('a', { modifiers: [ isMac ? 'Meta' : 'Control'] }),
```

*Note: isMac is a made up variable, you should determine if you have to use `Meta` (cmd key on mac) or `Control` on Linux/Windows*